# How to check current thread in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift3, nsthread

How do I check which one is the current thread in Swift 3?

In previous versions of Swift it was possible to check if the current thread was the main one by doing this:

```
NSThread.isMainThread()
```

Comment: Most of the responses here are no longer (Swift 5+) valid. Thread.isMainThread is a warning (and does nothing) in Swift 5 and will be an error in Swift 6.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Looks like it's simply `Thread.isMainThread` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 142):

`Thread.isMainThread` will return a boolean indicating if you're currently on the main UI thread. But this will not give you the current thread. It will only tell you if you are on the main or not.

`Thread.current` will return the current thread you are on.

Answer (score 44):

I've made an extension to print the thread and queue:

```
extension Thread {
    class func printCurrent() {
        print("\r⚡️: \(Thread.current)\r" + ": \(OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.label ?? "None")\r")
    }
}
```

`Thread.printCurrent()`

The result would be:

```
⚡️: <NSThread: 0x604000074380>{number = 1, name = main}
: com.apple.main-thread
```

Also recommend to use (not for async/await code):

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    /// - Parameter closure: Closure to execute.
    func dispatchMainIfNeeded(_ closure: @escaping VoidCompletion) {
        guard self === DispatchQueue.main && Thread.isMainThread else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure)
            return
        }

        closure()
    }
}

DispatchQueue.main.dispatchMainIfNeeded { ... }
```

Comment: why do you check both `self === DispatchQueue.main` and `Thread.isMainThread`? It seems to be redundant

Answer (score 34):

**Swift 4 and above:**

`Thread.isMainThread` returns `Bool` stating that if the user is on Main Thread or Not, in case if someone wants to print the name of the queue/thread this extension will be helpful

```
extension Thread {

    var threadName: String {
        if let currentOperationQueue = OperationQueue.current?.name {
            return "OperationQueue: \(currentOperationQueue)"
        } else if let underlyingDispatchQueue = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.label {
            return "DispatchQueue: \(underlyingDispatchQueue)"
        } else {
            let name = __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)
            return String(cString: name, encoding: .utf8) ?? Thread.current.description
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
print(Thread.current.threadName)
```

Comment: `__dispatch_queue_get_label` is not a part of Swift stdlib, it's not available outside of Apple platform-only frameworks. Can't call it on Ubuntu, for example.

Comment: `__dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)` FINALLY something that works, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

## Swift 5+

Normally, we only need to know which queue the code is dispatched. So I separate the `threadName` and `queueName` into different properties to make it more clear.

```
extension Thread {
    var threadName: String {
        if isMainThread {
            return "main"
        } else if let threadName = Thread.current.name, !threadName.isEmpty {
            return threadName
        } else {
            return description
        }
    }
    
    var queueName: String {
        if let queueName = String(validatingUTF8: __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)) {
            return queueName
        } else if let operationQueueName = OperationQueue.current?.name, !operationQueueName.isEmpty {
            return operationQueueName
        } else if let dispatchQueueName = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.label, !dispatchQueueName.isEmpty {
            return dispatchQueueName
        } else {
            return "n/a"
        }
    }
}
```

Use cases:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   print(Thread.current.threadName)
   print(Thread.current.queueName)
}
// main
// com.apple.main-thread
```

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
   print(Thread.current.threadName)
   print(Thread.current.queueName)
}
// <NSThread: 0x600001cd9d80>{number = 3, name = (null)}
// com.apple.root.default-qos
```

Answer (score 13):

When using GCD you can use *dispatchPrecondition* to check a dispatch condition necessary for further execution. This can be useful if you want to guarantee your code execution on correct thread. For example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(DispatchQueue.global())) // will assert because we're executing code on main thread
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In latest Swift 4.0 ~ 4.2, we can use `Thread.current`

See [Returns the thread object representing the current thread of execution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/thread/1410679-current)